# Extreme Heilbronn -- Maximal count of smallest triangle?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, extremal-combinatorics

For the [Heilbronn problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HeilbronnTriangleProblem.html), here's an extreme case I found with 300 triangles having the smallest area, on 84 points.

[image: Extreme Heilbronn]

Can anyone find a position with a higher repetition in the smallest triangle area? (zero area triangles don't count)